# Issues with navbar and button

Tags: angular

What am I doing wrong in my code below that I do not get **Recipes** and **Shopping List** and **Manage**?

I have checked the tags and bootstrap classes, but I only get **Recipe Book** and not the others...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">

            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                Recipe Book
            </a>

        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shopping List</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">Manage<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fetch Data List</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `collapse navbar-collapse`  with just `navbar-default` and the missing items will appear.

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
      
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">

            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                Recipe Book
            </a>

        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shopping List</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fetch Data List</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
</nav>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't wanna include JQuery. This is an html file in an Angular project that uses Bootstrap classes, so it should work just like this, but I think I am missing something that it doesn't work. Can you see what is wrong in the content that I have provided?